# Fluid column and fixed buffer columns - how to make their height equal to fluid column using css?

Tags: html, css

I want these empty divs to have the same height as fluid div.

http://jsfiddle.net/QLdZs/

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="buffer"></div>
    <div class="buffer"></div>
    <div class="buffer"></div>
    <div id="content">
        this is content<br/>
        lalala<br/>
        lala<br/>
        lala<br/>
        lalalalala lala la<br/>
        o sole mio<br/>
    </div>
 </div>
```

css:

```
#container {
 overflow:hidden;   
}
.buffer {
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
    width:100px;
    min-height:10px;
    border-right:1px solid white;
 }
#content {
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:green;
}
```

I know I can make `#container {position:relative;}`, and then set `.buffer {position:absolute;height:100%;}` but I'll have to set positions for all these buffers seperately, and set margin to `#content` div. Sometimes I'll have two, three buffers, sometimes none. So this is not the best way of doing it.

Do you have any good idea how can I do this?

Comment: Please include the relevant html/css within your question.  Links are useful too, but the question should be self sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Check this article out, I think it's what you need:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

I usually just used fixed heights, though.

Quoted from the article:

```
<div id="container3">
    <div id="container2">
        <div id="container1">
            <div id="col1">Column 1</div>
            <div id="col2">Column 2</div>
            <div id="col3">Column 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
#container3 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:green;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
#container2 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
    position:relative;
    right:30%;
}
#container1 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    right:40%;
}
#col1 {
    float:left;
    width:26%;
    position:relative;
    left:72%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#col2 {
    float:left;
    width:36%;
    position:relative;
    left:76%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#col3 {
    float:left;
    width:26%;
    position:relative;
    left:80%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: As I understand it makes these columns to look the same height, but I need my divs not only look the same height, but be the same height.

Comment: I think you may need to go with javascript then. What do you need them the same height for?